# Conditions in Firebase Remote Config Defaults

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to set up Firebase Remote Config. One of important parts in my project is correct localization. So I have conditions for different languages set up in console. But now I'd like to make defaults xml. [Example on github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/config/app/src/main/res/xml/remote_config_defaults.xml) is to simple. There are only few values without any conditions. Documentation does not describe this format at all. So I'm wondering if it is possible to specify all my localizations in defaults.xml and how do I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaults file can't be used to specify conditions.  It is just key/value pairs as shown.  These values will be used before anything is actually fetched and cached from Firebase, for example, the first time your app is launched.

Comment: But language is available on device, there is no need to fetch it.
So there is no other way of doing this except filling defaults with empty values, wrapping RemoteConfig with checks and return string resources in case it is empty ?

Comment: Android has its own way of localizing strings for values compiled into the app.  Use that instead.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about. If I want to use localized string in remote config it is possible to config it in console but it is not possible to setup defaults. In order to have localized defaults I have to write wrapper that use system localization.

Comment: BTW maybe you can share some insights on how it works ? If these values are stored under the same key suffixed by condition might it be possible to specify these key-value pairs for different languages in my defaults xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put localized xml with defaults in folder `xml-fr` for French or `xml-ru` for Russian (just `xml` for other localizations).

Comment: Then you have two sources of truth: Resources and RemoteConfig. I'd like to be able to use RemoteConfig only

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem for the past one day. Found a solution a few minutes back.

Firstly, create the required localized files for Remote Config Defaults.
[image: Screenshot of localized remote_config_defaults.xml]

Then, before you call `fetchAndActive()` just get the required value. This will give you the values from the remote_config_defualts.xml

```
/*Use remoteConfig object to get values from defaults. 
If you have added multiple locales then it will give the values
from the respective locale basis on your device language.
Make sure you have used the same key for all the locales.*/
val defaultValue =
        remoteConfig.getValue(YOUR_KEY).asString()

    remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
        .addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
//Use remoteConfig object to get the values from Firebase.
            }
        }
```